# Are 'const' values inside a container actually disallowed?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Why can't I put structures with `const` values inside a container like `std::vector`? *(I understand the technical reason the compiler is reporting, I'm just uncertain the compiler/collection should be doing it this way)*

For example, something quite simple:

```
struct sample {
    int const a;
};
std::vector<sample> v;
v.push_back( sample{12} );
```

This gives an error (at least in GCC) about using the deleted `operator=`. But I don't see why it should be using `operator=`. It shouldn't need to use the copy operator when constructing this vector. Should it not be using the copy contructor an in-place new, which is perfectly allowed. For example, the following is okay:

```
sample a;
new (&a) sample{12};
```

Calling the destructor of `sample` is also fine. That is, there are enough allowed operations on this type to construct a vector yet I am unable to do so. I thought C++11 with rvalue's and move semantics may also help here, but perhaps I'm wrong on that.

What part of the standard specifically disallow this, or is indeed a compiler error (unlikely)?

Comment: Calling the constructor should be fine, and works on my GCC.  CopyAssignable is only required for certain operations.

Comment: I meant it fails on an operationg, not just construction (I added the `push_back` call).

Comment: `push_back` doesn't require CopyAssignable either...

Comment: Oops, not a duplicate, this is slightly different to the one I linked to, sorry. However, the code compiles fine with `-std=c++11`, which GCC are you using?

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using? This works for me on 4.7.3. I t also works on clang 3.2. Both with `-std=c++11` of course.

Comment: See compiling GCC 4.7.2 sample [here](http://ideone.com/NDy4Qf).

Comment: I suspect the OP forgot to use -std=c++11 or is using a pre-C++11 version of GCC, before we fixed vector to meet the new requirements. Or is compiling something different not shown here.

Comment: I'm using GCC 4.6.4... so I guess 4.7 corrects the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My reading of the Standard (N3290) says that your `push_back` is valid.

23.2.3 para 16 (Table 101 — Optional sequence container operations) says that `push_back` only requires of `T` that it is `MoveInsertable`.

23.2.1 para 13 defines `MoveInsertable` : the following expression shall be valid: 
`allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v);`

20.6.8.2 para 5 specifies that by default (e.g., for default allocator) `construct` calls placement new -- much like your expectation.

Regards,
&rzej

Comment: I may be in error, but should you not make your argument with the `push_back` overload which takes `rv`, and thus requires `MoveInsertable`?

Comment: @dionadar: you are absolutely correct. I will edit the reply.

Answer (score 2):

So if you are using a conformant compiler/stdlib there will be a:

```
 vector<T>::push_back(T&&)
```

overload which the temporary `sample{12}` will bind to, causing it to call the move constructor of T at the reserved uninitialized storage element at `v.end()`, using the temporary as a parameter.  A copy constructor or assignment should not be needed to support this.

A better way would be to add a constructor to `sample` and then you can call:

```
 v.emplace_back(12)
```

which apart from being more succinct will also avoid the move constructor as well.

As others have stated your compiler/stdlib is not conformant, upgrade to a newer version.